# (admin.E005) Both 'fieldsets' and 'fields' are specified

Tags: django-admin

i got System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced). i'm not sure what is the issue.
thanks for any help

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Student
# Register your models here.
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('__str__', 'first_name', 'nationality', 'birth_day')
    list_filter = ('first_name', 'nationality')
    search_fields = ('nationality',)
    search_help_text= ('search by nationality')
    fields = (('first_name', 'last_name'), 'nationality')
    fieldsets = (
        (
            'Basic Information',
            {
                'classes':('collapse',),
                'fields': (('first_name', 'last_name',),),
            }
        ),
    )
admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```